# Share session between web site and WordPress blog on the same server

Tags: php, wordpress, session

am using Yii framework as for web site and WP for a blog (don't ask why, I inherited this project). Yii is responsible for users (login/logout...), and in the blog (WP) I need to know when the user is logged in.

I tried setting session in Yii (**$_SESSION['key'] = $value **)and reading it in WP, but WP doesn't see the session (**echo $_SESSION['key'] **).

The domain for the site is domain.com, and for the blog is domain.com/blog

Is it possible to share session this way?

Comment: Yes it is possible.  But WordPress has some issues around `$_SESSION` variables.  WHERE or WHEN are you attempting to read the session in WP?

Comment: I set session first in the yii, and after that I go to wp  and try to read the session. The session (whole session) is empty.

Comment: Sasha - where in WP are you reading the SESSION? It matters, that's why I'm asking.  In your theme header.php file? In your theme functions.php file? IF so, WHERE in your functions.php file.  PLEASE share the specific code, otherwise I cannot help!

Comment: I am not at the comp at the moment - I am trying to read session in the header.php (simple if condition to check if the session key exists).

Comment: OK, that's too late.  You have to hook the `init` action.  I'd suggest reading this article: http://www.kanasolution.com/2011/01/session-variable-in-wordpress/